# Solution of Tricky Equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How would I solve $\cos(x) + \cosh(x) - e^x = 0$?  Any help would be great.  I'm in Calculus AB AP right now, but if the answer is above that, just right it out anyway.

Comment: a numerical method would help you

Comment: Start by simplifying $\cosh(x)-e^x$.

Comment: I'm closing due to lack of context because you've only posted the problem statement and may have missed out necessary portions of the question. I'd suspect such a problem is not a first year calculus question and that you haven't included all the necessary e.g. you aren't trying to find the solution, but rather show its existence.

Comment: This is not for calculus class, this is for me. I've always loved giving myself hard math problems, and they always bother me until they're solved.  Just to be clear, I'm looking for an exact answer.

Comment: If you just make up some random equation, you can't expect that there *is* an exact answer (in terms of familiar functions).

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(x) + \cosh(x) - e^x = 0$ can be simplified into $\cos (x)-\sinh (x)=0$

The equation has one root $x\in(0,\;1)$

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
x & \cos (x)-\sinh (x)\\
\hline
 -3. & 9.02788 \\
 -2. & 3.21071 \\
 -1. & 1.7155 \\
 0. & 1. \\
 1. & -0.634899 \\
 2. & -4.04301 \\
 3. & -11.0079 \\
\end{array}
$

which is also the only one because the derivative of LHS of the equation $\cos (x)-\sinh (x) is $-\sin (x)-\cosh (x)$

which is negative for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ because $-\sin(x)<\cosh(x)$, so the function is always decreasing and has one and only one root

Therefore we can start from $x_0=0.5$ with Newton method and define

$x_n=x_{n-1}-\dfrac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}$

After a few iteration we get the root $x=0.703291$

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
 n & x_n \\
\hline
 0 & 0.5 \\
 1 & 0.721827 \\
 2 & 0.703427 \\
 3 & 0.703291 \\
 4 & 0.703291 \\
\end{array}
$

Hope this helps